# Matplotlib: filled contour plot with transparent colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does somebody know – in Matplotlib – how to produce a good-looking filled contour plot with semi-transparent colors? If `contourf()` is passed a colormap with semi-transparent colors, it produces small gaps between the filled areas:

[image: small gaps between areas]

According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf), this is not a bug ("`contourf()` [...] does not draw the polygon edges"). To draw the edges, it is suggested to "add line contours with calls to `contour()`". But that doesn't look good either as the edges become too opaque:

[image: edges are too opaque]

You can play around with the `linewidth` argument of `contour()`, but that doesn't help much. Any ideas?

Here's the code that reproduces the problem (I use the object-oriented API, but the result is the same with `pyplot`):

```python
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

# generate some data
shape = (100, 100)
x_rng = np.linspace(-1, 1, shape[1])
y_rng = np.linspace(-1, 1, shape[0])
x, y = np.meshgrid(x_rng, y_rng)
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

# create figure
width_inch, height_inch = 5, 5  # results in 500x500px with dpi=100
fig = Figure()
fig.set_size_inches((width_inch, height_inch))
FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
ax = fig.add_axes([0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()

# define some colors with alpha < 1
alpha = 0.9
colors = [
    (0.1, 0.1, 0.5, alpha),  # dark blue
    (0.0, 0.7, 0.3, alpha),  # green
    (0.9, 0.2, 0.7, alpha),  # pink
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, alpha),  # black
    (0.1, 0.7, 0.7, alpha),  # light blue
]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
levels = np.array(np.linspace(0, z.max(), len(colors)))
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N)

# contourf plot produces small gaps between filled areas
cnt = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                  antialiased=True, linecolor='none')

# this fills the gaps, but it makes them too opaque
# ax.contour(x, y, z, levels, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
#            antialiased=True)

# the same is true for this trick:
# for c in cnt.collections:
#     c.set_edgecolor("face")

filename = "/tmp/contourf.png"
fig.savefig(filename, dpi=100, transparent=True, format="png")
```

PS: The same plot looks good with the SVG backend.

PPS: `pcolormesh()` has a similar problem:

```python
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
              edgecolor="face", antialiased=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: ``antialiased=True`` seems to have an effect (but turning it off doesn't produce a nice result either).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your problem, as 'good-looking' is somewhat subjective, but the only way to get an image that doesn't have any antialiasing issues, or jagged-edges, when zoomed in to that level would be to use a vector format, like SVG, EPS, etc (as you point out).

**SVG (Scalable vector graphics)**

[image]

If you turn off antialiasing, you can get rid of the blurring of edges and the 'opaqueness', but you will get a jagged-edge appearance to the circles at high zoom levels. You could try increasing the dpi to say, 300dpi, and saving as a tiff:

**Tiff, 300dpi, antialiasing=False**

[image]

Anti-aliasing is going to blend your image along the circle boundaries, so mixing the transparent pink and green is going produce a darker looking color, which might give the impression of looking more opaque, even if the transparency is notionally the same.

I got different-looking results from commenting in/out the following sections of your code, but the results are too subjective to say which is better looking:

Set the contours but not the edgecolor:

```
ax.contour(x, y, z, levels, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
            antialiased=True)

# the same is true for this trick:
# for c in cnt.collections:
#     c.set_edgecolor("face")
```

Don't set the contours, but set the edge color:

```
# ax.contour(x, y, z, levels, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
#            antialiased=True)

# the same is true for this trick:
 for c in cnt.collections:
     c.set_edgecolor("face")
```

But it's up to interpretation whether they look good. Another thing I found was that my image viewer has it's own anti-aliasing feature built in, so you might want to turn this off when trying to make comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for picking this up. I worked around the problem by plotting without transparency – using RGB colors as "placeholders" for RGBA colors – and applying transparency in a post-processing step.
I've upvoted your answer, but have not accepted it since it does not actually solve the original question.